# Query a Global Secondary Index using contains in DynamoDB local

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-dynamodb-local

I have `id` as the hash key of my table and `returnItemId` which is the GSI. The `returnItemId` is a string which contains values separated by commas. Given a number for the GSI, I want to be able to query and get the correct item that contains it by using `contains`

```html
var params = {
    "AttributeDefinitions": [ // describbes the key schema of the table
    {
      "AttributeName": "id",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "returnItemId",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
  ],
  // Hash for Primary Table
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "id",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    }
  ],

  "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
    {
      "IndexName": "ReturnItemIndex",
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "returnItemId", //must match one of attributedefinitions names
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        }
      ],
      "Projection": {
        "ProjectionType": "ALL"
      },
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
      }
    }
  ],

  "ProvisionedThroughput": {
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
  },


  "TableName": "my-table"
};
dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response

});
```

Then I am going to create 2 items

```html
var params = {
    TableName: 'my-table',
    Item: { 
    
        "id": "the_first_item",
        "returnItemId": "123,456,789"
    },
};
docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

And the second item

```html
var params = {
    TableName: 'my-table',
    Item: { 
    
        "id": "the_second_item",
        "returnItemId": "987,654,321"
    },
};
docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

The two items look like [image]

I am trying to run a query and get the correct item which contains `987` using the following query. Since my first item has `123,456,789` and the second item has `987,654,321` this method should return the second item.

```html
var params = {
    TableName: 'my-table',
    IndexName: 'ReturnItemIndex', // optional (if querying an index)
    KeyConditionExpression: 'contains(returnItemId, :return_id)',
    //FilterExpression: 'contains(returnItemId, :return_id)', // a string representing a constraint on the attribute
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':return_id': '987' },
};
docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

But am getting errors about using contains in keyconditionexpression. Is this method possible?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property

Comment: I've seen that link before but I don't think it answers my question. I've tried getting `contains` to work with `KeyConditions` but did not succeed

Comment: can you log the error also ?

Comment: It wasn't an error more so I don't understand if that was even a valid method. My stack overflow question is not about finding the correct resource but understanding if it's possible and if someone knows how to implement this solution

Comment: It is possible to to query, using `ConditionalOperator`, see how you can use this for your problem.

Comment: I figured out the solution without using ConditionalOperator. For those curious, use a dummy key value that is consistent across and use `contains` on the field you're interested in.

Comment: And it is not possible to use the conditional operator for key values in my particular scenario. Research is best advised before suggesting advice.

Answer (score 1):

`contains` can only be used in filters which means:
- query or scan operations will traverse all data to apply your filters
- your cost of read operations will include all data read not just matched data
- with contains "12", you would probably match "123" and "124" too
- better than comma separated is to use StringSet or NumberSet data type

I would suggest another layout
Keyschema:
Partiton Key: id
Sort Key: returnItemId
GSI
Partition Key: returnItemId

Data:

```
------------------------------------
| id                | returnItemId |
------------------------------------
| "the_first_item"  | "123"        |
| "the_first_item"  | "456"        |
| "the_first_item"  | "789"        |
| "the_second_item" | "987"        |
| "the_second_item" | "654"        |
| "the_second_item" | "321"        |
------------------------------------
```

then query GSI for key condition returnItemId = 987 ( no filter expression )

Comment: Great answer @adrian-praja, can you provide sources for this too?